# recreating a smartart chevron list from ms word using css

Tags: css, html, ms-word

I'm trying to recreate a vertical chevron list from Microsoft word to a page using CSS so I can create multiple step by step lists such as this (shown in picture).

[image]

I'm able to create small boxes but nothing that resembles the image

```
.stepbystep {
    border:5px solid rgb(65,47,143);
    background-color: rgb(222,221,228);
    color:  rgb(65,47,143);
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 150px;
    background:  url(../graphics/common/step.png) top left no-repeat;
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but using a few pseudo-elements it can be done.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GxJpy)

**HTML**

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="one" href="#">Wake Up</a></li>
    <li><a class="two" href="#">Step 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="three" href="#">Step 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="four" href="#">Step 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  width:250px;
  margin:25px auto;
 }

li {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:darkblue;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:block;
  background:white;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid darkblue;
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  line-height:50px;
}


a:before {
  color:white;
  background:darkblue;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  line-height:80px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:0;
  font-size:0.75em;
  text-align:center;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  left:0;
  border:25px solid transparent;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  z-index: 25;
}

li:before {
  top:0;
  border-top-color:white;
}

li:after {
  top:100%;
  border-top-color:darkblue;;
}

.one:before {
    content:"Step 1";
}

.two:before {
    content:"Step 2";
}

.three:before {
    content:"Step 3";
}

.four:before {
    content:"Step 4";
}
```

Comment: looks good... will try this and get back to you tomorrow morning

Comment: Codepen updated with additional mark-up for multi-line  list text.